# Scroller and table column not visible

Tags: java, swing

I am new to GUI coding in Java (using swing) and I am stuck at a point where the JTable is missing its column headers and there is no scroller around the table.

Image of what it looks like: http://i.gyazo.com/28a66d42bd9365b2c3c9bfd7c8907cee.png

Code:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null }, }, new String[] {
            "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column",
            "New column" }));
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add your JTable to the JScrollPane's viewport as its view. This is easiest done by passing the table into the JScrollPane's constructor:

```
// create JTable, table, first
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

// now add scrollPane to GUI
```

Alternatively, you could create things in the order that you do, and add the JTable explicitly to the viewport as its view:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Foo2b extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] COLUMNS = { "Column One", "Column Two",
         "Column Three", "Column Four", "Column Five" };
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 30;
   private DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, ROW_COUNT);
   private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

   public Foo2b() {
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Foo2b mainPanel = new Foo2b();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2b");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Second solution worked great! Also, thanks for the example :)